# Twitter Streaming API Python library with proxy support?

Tags: python, api, twitter, proxy, streaming

I am looking for a Twitter Streaming API Python library with proxy support. I love tweepy, but unfortunately I haven't seen a way to use an HTTP proxy. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not? Setting HTTP_PROXY environment variables don't work?

Comment: I have strong doubts in your claims...

Comment: Yep, setting HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY does not have any effect. The proxy does not use authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/ducu/tweepy/commit/bf6f4f2bb8f856de30557a9a1aa8799048433814) tweepy commit; it uses urllib2 for executing APIMethods through proxies.

Comment: Thank you @systempuntoout, but unfortunately the author is not willing to accept the pull request (for whatever reason). I have [asked](https://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy/pull/80) him whether it's going to be merged (and also sent him a PM), but to no avail.

Comment: @else why don't you patch the library yourself?

Comment: because I don't want to redistribute the patched version.

Comment: @else can't you include the original version, monkey patching just the binding.py module?

Answer (score 2):

Tweepy uses `httplib` internally which is too low level to have proxy settings. You have to change `Stream._run()` method to connect to proxy instead of target host and use full (with scheme and host) URL in request.